# Does SVM classification only used for classifying dataset with only 2 labels?

Tags: image, machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm new to svm and I've been looking for a svm to use. From all the ones that I've seen, the training label vector is basically by 1 vector of 1 and -1. I don't understand why this is so. I was under the assumption that each row of the training vector should be a unique number that labels its respective trained instance.

So just assume I have a data set with m labels with n instances and each instance is a d dimension vector. It seems weird to use label vector only contains -1 and 1. But I really do not know to to separate the m labels in hyperplane. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM is internally a binary classifier. This means that it can **only separate two labels**. Thus it is well suited for problems where the question can be expressed in the form "Does given vector has property X?" and the answer is either yes (+1) or no (-1).

But there are so many problems in real life which require more labels, what to do about it? In order to solve problems with m labels, like for example "What type of animal is on the picture: cat, dog or horse?" you basiccally create *ensemble* of SVMs, which **vote** for particular labels. There are many possibilities, but two of them are most popular:

- One vs. all approach. Given m labels you create m models, i'th SVM is trained to recognize if the object has label "i" or not, thus you train it on label "i" as +1, and with all other samples as -1. Then, when it comes to classification - you ask each SVM if it recognizes the sample - if there are any ties - you use SVM decision function (distance to hyperplane) to break it (the most distant one wins)
- One vs one approach. Now you create m(m-1)/2 SVMs. Each answers the question "is this sample more i-labeled or j-labeled", for each pair (i, j) of labels (and there are m(m-1)/2 ways of select two labels among m ones). Thus again - during classification you ask each such SVM, and they "vote", you sum votes and the label with most votes - wins (again in case of ties you can use decision functions).